# Efficient group by and where clause in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am having **weekly( say 5 weeks)** sales and baskets for **product and store combination**, i want to find the total spend and visits of product **(irrespective of store)** for a particular **week(say 201520)**" i.e. 20th week of year 2015. the moment i select a week , there can be some product that are not sold in that week. but i **do not want to remove them from my group by**. Essentially i want all the products sold in 5 weeks , but if a product is not sold in the week i selected above , i want it to be present in my final dataFrame with aggregated numbers to be 0. Sample data.(lets **assume prod 122 is not sold in week 201520**)

```
prod store week    baskets sales
123  112   201518  20      100.45
123  112   201519  21      89.65
123  112   201520  22      1890.54
122  112   201518  10      909.99
```

sample output (for 201520)

```
prod total_baskets   total_sales  spend_per_basket
123  22              1890.54      85.93363636
122  0               0            0
```

i know this can be done using **groupby** using pandas. But i am doing multiple steps. i am looking for a more pythonic and efficient way. currently
i am first selecting the week for which i am doing groupby.
then creating a list of all product present in my inital weekly dataset.
then remerging back with the group by data. I find this non - efficient. please help. Also need to create **spend per basket . if total_baskets > 0 then spend_per_basket is total_sales/ total_baskets. else 0**  TIA.
 dummy code:

```
trans_for_my_week=weekly_trans[weekly_trans['week']==201520]    
avg_sales=pd.DataFrame(trans_for_my_week.groupby(['prod']).agg({'baskets':      {'total_baskets':'sum'},
                                                 'sales' :{'total_sales':'sum'}}))
avg_sales_period_0.columns=avg_sales_period_0.columns.droplevel(0)
avg_sales_period_0=avg_sales_period_0.reset_index()
```

and so on

On using the solution provided below: On writing the following code, i am getting some error:

```
x=round(res.sales / res.baskets,4)
x.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(['spend_per_basket', res.columns.get_level_values(1).drop_duplicates()])
```

print(x)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-fbb15ec86cc6> in <module>()
      7 
      8 x=round(res.sales / res.baskets,4)
----> 9 x.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(['spend_per_basket', res.columns.get_level_values(1).drop_duplicates()])
     10 print(x)

/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/indexes/multi.py in from_product(cls, iterables, sortorder, names)
   1022         from pandas.tools.util import cartesian_product
   1023 
-> 1024         labels, levels = _factorize_from_iterables(iterables)
   1025         labels = cartesian_product(labels)
   1026 

/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/categorical.py in _factorize_from_iterables(iterables)
   2066         # For consistency, it should return a list of 2 lists.
   2067         return [[], []]
-> 2068     return map(list, lzip(*[_factorize_from_iterable(it) for it in iterables]))

/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/categorical.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   2066         # For consistency, it should return a list of 2 lists.
   2067         return [[], []]
-> 2068     return map(list, lzip(*[_factorize_from_iterable(it) for it in iterables]))

/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/categorical.py in _factorize_from_iterable(values)
   2028 
   2029     if not is_list_like(values):
-> 2030         raise TypeError("Input must be list-like")
   2031 
   2032     if is_categorical(values):

TypeError: Input must be list-like
```

Comment: You find your code "non-efficient" in what way?

Comment: in terms of code length , instead of writing multiple lines of codes , can i do this using itertools or groupby and where clause in a shorter piece of code.(or built in functions) and why do i have to reset the index everytime i do a groupby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE2:** adding new calculated multi-level column:

```
In [8]: x = res.sales / res.baskets

In [9]: x
Out[9]:
week   201518    201519     201520
prod
122   90.9990       NaN        NaN
123    5.0225  4.269048  85.933636

In [10]: x.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['spend_per_basket'], res.columns.get_level_values(1).drop_duplicates()])

In [11]: x
Out[11]:
     spend_per_basket
               201518    201519     201520
prod
122           90.9990       NaN        NaN
123            5.0225  4.269048  85.933636

In [12]: res = res.join(x)

In [13]: res
Out[13]:
     baskets                 sales                 spend_per_basket
week  201518 201519 201520  201518 201519   201520           201518    201519     201520
prod
122       10      0      0  909.99   0.00     0.00          90.9990       NaN        NaN
123       20     21     22  100.45  89.65  1890.54           5.0225  4.269048  85.933636
```

PS [here is very well documented multiindexing (multi-level) pandas techniques with lots of examples](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html)

**UPDATE:** inspired by [@JoeR's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38801480/5741205) - here is modified `pivot_table()` version:

```
res = df.pivot_table(index='prod', columns='week', values=['baskets','sales'], aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)

In [189]: res
Out[189]:
     baskets                 sales
week  201518 201519 201520  201518 201519   201520
prod
122       10      0      0  909.99   0.00     0.00
123       20     21     22  100.45  89.65  1890.54

In [190]: res[[('baskets',201519)]]
Out[190]:
     baskets
week  201519
prod
122        0
123       21

In [192]: res.ix[122, [('sales',201519)]]
Out[192]:
       week
sales  201519    0.0
Name: 122, dtype: float64
```

you can also flatten your column levels as follows:

```
In [194]: res2 = res.copy()

In [196]: res2.columns = ['{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format(col) for col in res2.columns]

In [197]: res2
Out[197]:
      baskets_201518  baskets_201519  baskets_201520  sales_201518  sales_201519  sales_201520
prod
122               10               0               0        909.99          0.00          0.00
123               20              21              22        100.45         89.65       1890.54
```

but i would keep it as multilevel column so you could use advanced indexing (like in the example above)

**OLD answer:**

I'd calculate it once for all your data:

```
from itertools import product

In [165]: %paste
g = df.groupby(['week', 'prod']).agg({'baskets':'sum', 'sales':'sum'}).reset_index()
al = pd.DataFrame(list(product(df['prod'].unique(), df.week.unique())), columns=['prod','week'])

res = pd.merge(al, g, on=['prod','week'], how='left').fillna(0)
## -- End pasted text --

In [166]: res
Out[166]:
   prod    week    sales  baskets
0   123  201518   100.45     20.0
1   123  201519    89.65     21.0
2   123  201520  1890.54     22.0
3   122  201518   909.99     10.0
4   122  201519     0.00      0.0
5   122  201520     0.00      0.0
```

Comment: +1 Thanks MaxU. This is what i am looking for. Apparently i will have to just select the columns of week 201520. for each sales and visit. Need the index to be reset. coz next step was to create and average sales per visit column in the same dataframe

Comment: @Mukul, i've added some code for flattening the multilevel columns. PS don't forget to accept / upvote JoeR's answer, as he was first who came up with the `pivot_table` idea

Comment: brilliant MaxU. Thanks. a lot. I think now i can not reset the index and create the new column sales per visit for each product. i.e where baskets >0 i can calculate the sales_201520 / visits_201520. Can you help in adding this column spend_per_visit_201520 please.( this column will be 0 is basket is = 0). Already upvoted the answer

Comment: @Mukul, can you extend your question (or better create a new one) so that we can see a source data set, including `visits` column and post desired / expected data set?

Comment: actually visits is same as baskets. edited the question. TIA :)

Comment: @Mukul, i've extended my answer - please check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120299/discussion-between-mukul-and-maxu).

Comment: Hi maxu, there has been some changes in the python version, this does not seem to  work , getting the following error :     TypeError: Input must be list-like

Comment: @Mukul, could you update your question with a full error traceback?

Comment: can you  please also explain what was the issue and where did you make the change ?

Comment: @Mukul, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38801383/revisions) - `'spend_per_basket'` --> `['spend_per_basket']`

Comment: Awesome, just because of versioning this has occurred. Thank again. Really helpful

Answer (score 3):

You can also get what you need using [pivot_table](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html), although it's a little different approach, *but you were looking for a one line code*:

```
print(pd.pivot_table(df, index = 'week', columns = 'prod', values = 'sales', aggfunc = 'sum').fillna(0))
```

Output:

```
prod       122      123
week                   
201518  909.99   100.45
201519    0.00    89.65
201520    0.00  1890.54
```

Comment: I think this is the best option (+1) if OP can live with this data representation. I'd do it bit differently though: `df.pivot_table(index='prod', columns='week', values=['baskets','sales'], aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)`

Comment: this is it :). Thanks Joe, and apparently what MaxU modified is awesome. Will this be a dataframe ? how can i rename the columns names, asking coz i want to create average sales per visit for a particular week. which is (sales of 201612 / visits of 201612  ) . in short add another column avg_spend_per_basket_per_week

Comment: @MaxU Thanks for the +1. Yes, I like your version of the `pivot_table`. I appreciate it. Also +1 for your answer as well.

Comment: @Mukul Yes, I like MaxU's modification to the `pivot_table` as well. Yes, there is a way to add an an other column and create a new dataframe. As you already accepted one of the answers, you might want to address the new column issue in a new question as it would be to much to add to this current question and a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest and more "Pythonic" solution will involve at least two steps: groupby, then a merge. And you can do it as follows:

```
# First create a container DataFrame to hold the data:
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['a', 'b'], df[0].unique()])
output = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

# Then the groupby magic
agg_sales = weekly_trans.groupby(['week','prod']).agg({'baskets' : {'total_baskets':'sum'},
                                                       'sales'   : {'total_sales'  :'sum'}})
agg_sales = agg_sales.unstack() # This will set your 'prod' as columns
output = pd.concat([output, agg_sales], axis=0)

# And you can do that in one line, if you need to:
output = pd.concat([output, weekly_trans.groupby(['week','prod']).\
                       agg({'baskets' : {'total_baskets':'sum'},
                            'sales'   : {'total_sales'  :'sum'}}).\
                           unstack()], axis=0)
```